# How many spells can a bard have at level 3?

Tags: dnd-5e, bard, spell-slots

It seems to me like I get 3 cantrips because I'm level 3 and 4 1st level spells and 5 2nd level spells. Is this right?

How many spells can a bard have at level 3?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se! Please take our [tour] to see how we work and to earn a nifty badge! About your question though, have you tried reading the "Spellcasting" section of the Bard class. If so, what about it exactly is unclear?

Comment: There is a chart on the Bard page that shows that, at level 3, you would *know* a total of 6 non-cantrip spells, and that you can cast two level 2 spells and cast four level 1 spells, but the information you provided matches none of that.  Could you provide some clarification?

Comment: To clarify, you want to know how many a bard usually has? Or are you asking what's the maximum number?

Comment: @JamieBrace: "Read the book to me" questions are [not off-topic](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4825/can-we-have-a-rtfm-equivalent-in-the-vote-to-close-options) at this time. Downvoting is the desired response to such questions.

Comment: Can you explain how you got those numbers? Maybe if we understood how you got them we can better address your confusion.

Comment: So i got the numbers that cantrips are 0 so 0+3 is 3 and level1 is 1+my level3 and level 2spells are2+3=5. So can someone tell how many spells do i know on level 3

Answer (score 9):

## No, your numbers are not correct.

If you look at the [Bard Table](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/bard#TheBardTable) in the players handbook or on DND Beyond you will see that it lists the number of Cantrips known, Spells known and Spell slots for each Bard level.

**You will see that at Level 3 you should have:**

- **Cantrips known: 2**
- **Spells known: 6**
- **1st level spell slots: 4**
- **2nd level spell slots: 2**

In terms of the level of your spells, in the Spells Known section of the Bard [Class Features](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/bard#ClassFeatures) you will see that:

- When you level up you learn 1 new spell.
- The new spell must be of a level that you have Spell Slots for.
- In addition you can choose to replace one of your existing spells with a new one.

Based on this, at 2nd level you will have 5 known 1st level spells.  When you level up to 3rd level, you can (1) learn a new spell of 1st or 2nd level and (2) you can also replace one of you 1st level spells with a 2nd level spell if you wish.

**Thus, you will know 6 spells, with at most 2 of them being 2nd level spells and the rest being 1st level spells.**

Comment: Oops, typo, have fixed now. Thanks David Croffron.

Comment: fixed a couple more typos.

Answer (score 2):

## That is not correct

You can find this information listed in the Player's Handbook in the table under the Bard class description.

If you read the line for level 3 you will see that a 3rd level Bard will know 6 spells and 2 cantrips. They also have 4 1st level spell slots and 2 2nd level spell slots with which to cast those spells.

Answer (score 1):

### No.

As a 3rd level bard you have access to 2 cantrips and 6 known spells; also 4 1st level spell slots and 2 2nd level spell slots to cast those known spells. You had 5 known spells at 2nd level and got one more known spell at 3rd level. However, when you gain a level of bard, you can choose one bard spell you know and replace it with another bard spell from the bard spell list that you're able to cast at your new level. This spell can be of inferior, same or superior level than the spell you're swapping.